# How can I know how to distort the shadows and where to place them correctly?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, perspective, shadows

I have this image (1) of a man in front of a promotional wall. I need to add shadows to the wall and the carpet so that it looks more realistic.

How can I know where to place the shadows? If the wall was "2d", then it would be easier because youtube is full of tutorials for that. I have no idea what to do when the wall is in that kind of direction.

If I should have a reference image, what is the easiest way to find one? I tried to google "man in movie premiere" and similar but didn't really find anything good.

Image (2) is an example of something I tried to do.

[image]

[image]

Comment: The image looks fake on so many levels, that a shadowless wall does not look so off. Try making it look like a collage.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is with the shadows on the floor. Where the floor and wall meet, the shadows would change direction.

Here's a very rough diagram

[image]

Comment: To complement: 1. Parallel shadow on the wall. 2. Perspective shadow on the floor to join the feet to the wall's shadow. 3. Use some blur.

Comment: @Rafael - yes, I didn't go into that much detail ;)  Merry Christmas!

Answer (score -1):

A man who has a suit this luminous doesn't make shadows, he illuminates his environment and also a part of his own head.

[image]

Comment: thanks! Where can I learn more about this? e.g, what video or article should I go through to understand realize this the next time?

Comment: @haripommi the suit looked too bright. This was the easiest way out and it's surely written in no books which teach realistic drawing. There's also a way out by using shadows, but then there should be some shadows and maybe more glosses, too on the suit. To learn some ideas of realistic drawing get the classic book  of Andrew Loomis. It's available for free as PDF https://illustrationage.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/andrew-loomis-successful-drawing.pdf You must imagine where the light comes from to be able to construct shadows. Finally it's based on 3D space geometry.

Comment: (continued) A strong  light coming from a large area distant source behind the camera and a nearly holographically reflecting metallic suit would together be a good reason to accept your image with no shadows. Add only some light to the head to make the face recognizable.

Comment: Where can I learn more about this? Art/illustration class. Learn to do it by hand, then doing it digitally is easy